# How do I add hair (3D segments, coord from file) to a head?

Tags: mesh, hair

[Blender newbie here] I have the 3D mesh of a head, saved as a `.obj` file, and I need to place some hair on top of it. The hairstyle is defined in a `.data` file, which consists of 10.000 hair strands. Each hair strand is made of 100 segments.

How can I place the hair on top of the head? Should I convert the `.hair` file in a `.obj` mesh? If so, how do you recommend to do it? Thanks heaps!

I am working with the USC - HairSalon dataset, which you can download from [here](http://www-scf.usc.edu/%7Eliwenhu/SHM/database.html).

Comment: I still haven't found a way to do this using Blender. As a temporary fix, I managed to load the convert the hairstyle in a set of 3D points, store these in a csv file and display both the points and the head in 3D using ParaView.

Comment: You could import the data with a Python script and create the hair mesh. Then you can convert it into curves and extrude them for stylized hair or use the HairNet add-on to create particle hair. (oof, it's a 3.2 GB solid database file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a script that reads the data file and creates the strands of the hair mesh.

[image: screenshot]

The script is straightforward. It reads the file, checks the number of strands, then reads them one by one and creates the edges of the strands. Empty roots will be skipped.

To run the script, go to the *Scripting* workspace and select menu *Text > New* to create a new text data block. Then copy & paste the script. Adjust the path of the directory for the data files and the ID that defines which of the files you want to import. Finally, press the run button.

If something goes wrong you need to check the system console (main menu *Window > Toggle System Console*).

Keep in mind that a hairstyle can have up to 1 million vertices. If you want to import more than one I strongly recommend only keeping every Nth strand to reduce the amount of incoming data. (Reducing the number of vertices is more difficult because it shortens the hair.)

[image: performance test]
<sup>Performance test - imported all 343 hair styles but only 1250 strands for each head (=12.5%), 5GB RAM usage</sup>

```
# Importer for USC-HairSalon: A 3D Hairstyle Database for Hair Modeling
#  https://www-scf.usc.edu/%7Eliwenhu/SHM/database.html
import bpy
import bmesh
import math
from mathutils import Vector
import struct
import array

data_path = "C:/tmp"      # <------------------- path
hairstyle_id = "00144"    # <------------------- strand id

def addStrand(vertices, edges, strand_data_xyz):
    
    # add first vertex of strand
    xyz_idx = 0 
    vec =  Vector((strand_data_xyz[xyz_idx], strand_data_xyz[xyz_idx+1], strand_data_xyz[xyz_idx+2]))
    vertices.append(vec) 
    
    num_verts_to_add = int(len(strand_data_xyz) / 3)
    edge_vidx = len(vertices)
    
    for i in range(1, num_verts_to_add):
        xyz_idx += 3
        vec =  Vector((strand_data_xyz[xyz_idx], strand_data_xyz[xyz_idx+1], strand_data_xyz[xyz_idx+2]))
        vertices.append(vec) 
        
        edges.append((edge_vidx-1, edge_vidx))
        edge_vidx += 1

# -----------------------------------------
# data of the mesh
vertices = []  # XYZ coords
edges = []
faces = []

fin = open(f"{data_path}/strands{hairstyle_id}.data", "rb")

num_strands = struct.unpack('<i', fin.read(4))[0]
print("num_strands = ", num_strands)
assert num_strands == 10000, f"exspected 10000 strands, got: {num_strands}"

strand_idx = 0
while (strand_idx < num_strands):

    # read num of verts of strand
    strand_idx = strand_idx + 1    
    num_verts = struct.unpack('<i', fin.read(4))[0]
    assert num_verts == 1 or num_verts == 100, f"num_verts should be 1 or 100, got: {num_verts}"
    
    # read strand
    strand_data_xyz = array.array('f') 
    strand_data_xyz.fromfile(fin, 3 * num_verts) # vert's XYZ corrds

    if (num_verts < 2):  # skip empty roots
        continue
    
    addStrand(vertices, edges, strand_data_xyz.tolist())

fin.close()

print("Data read, creating hair object...")

# create the mesh
hair_mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new(f"hair_mesh_{hairstyle_id}")
hair_mesh.from_pydata(vertices, edges, faces)
hair_mesh.update()

# create object from mesh
hair_object = bpy.data.objects.new(f"hair style {hairstyle_id}", hair_mesh)
# get collection
collection_name = 'USC-HairSalon (imported hair styles)'
hair_collection = bpy.data.collections.get(collection_name)
if hair_collection is None:
    hair_collection = bpy.data.collections.new(collection_name)
    bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(hair_collection)
# add object to scene collection
hair_collection.objects.link(hair_object)

# fix rotation (90° X-axis)
hair_object.rotation_euler[0] = math.radians(90)
#select object & apply rotation
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = hair_object
hair_object.select_set(True)
bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(rotation=True)
```

**Converting the Hair**

With the [HairNet](https://github.com/Jandals/HairNet/releases) add-on, the hair strands can be converted into particle hair.

Or you can convert the strands (mesh) into curves and vice versa (menu *Object > Convert > ...*). Curves can be extruded (*[Object Data Properties > Geometry](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/curves/properties/geometry.html)*) and converted back into a mesh if you want. If you pick a few strands you can create polygon hair that way ([Blender Tutorial - Hair With Curves](https://youtu.be/t2XjdzzWCqI)).